# Two overlapping layouts inside another layout

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I need 2 relative layouts to overlap in a parent layout. I'm not sure what the parent layout should be, but I think it has to be FrameLayout.

```
<FrameLayout>
   <RelativeLayout id=layout_one>
       <Button></Button>
       <ImageView></ImageView>
       ...
   </RelativeLayout>
   <RelativeLayout id=layout_two>
        <Button id = a></Button>
        <Button id = b></Button>
        ...
   </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Only one of the RelativeLayouts will be seen at a time. At first it is "layout_two". Then when Button "a" is clicked "layout_two" needs to be invisible and "layout_one" must appear. However, clicking Button a doesn't call onClick method, although I can see the button. Is there better way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Make Relative Layout as parent and then put your layouts on it.what I suggest is use Relative.

Comment: I did.The same effect.May be there are specific parameters to each of layout that I'm not using incorrect? I'm making all three layouts fill_parent height and width. They all have background image and id. Other than that I'm not specifing anything in attributes. Am I missing smth?

Comment: tell me exactly whatever you want to implement,then I can help you with all the code.